# Implement RPC with underlying request/response protocol (JSON-RPC on SIP)

Tags: java, callback, sip, rpc

Look at the following use case.

I have a client (Java) application, which wants to get/set the state of another, remote application (C). The communication between them is done via SIP, which is run in another thread.

The SIP interface can do the following:

sendMessage
onRequest

I have two ideas for the architecture:

**RPC (JSON-RPC)**

Define a class which does the marshalling/unmarshalling for JSONRPCRequests and JSONRPCResponse (http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0-base.html)

Define a Invoker class, which has something like a **call(server, name, arguments)** method.

In the Invoker class, the name and arguments are put into a JSONRPCRequest and sent via the SIP layer sendMessage

Now comes my problem. How do i actually get the right back to the caller? The control flow is now:

The onRequest method is called, but I do now know whether it is the answer to my previous call. What i do is putting all responses reaching my server into a Map, and just poll that list in the Invoker.

A rough sketch might be;

**Invoker (provides API to client)**

```
class Invoker {

    private Channel channel;

    public Invoker(Channel channel) { this.channel = channel; }

    public Object call(String server, String name, Object .. args) {
        JSONRPCRequest req = ...;
        channel.sendMessage(server, req.toString());
        while( ! channel.hasResponse(req.id()) {
            Thread.sleep(42);
        }
        return channel.getResponse(req.id()).result();        
    }

}
```

**Channel (interface to messenger):**

```
class Channel {

    private Map<Object, JSONRPCResponse> responses = new //;

    private Sip sip = new Sip() {
        public void onRequest(String msg) {
            JSONRPCResponse response = JSONRPCResponse.parse(msg);
            responses.put(msg.id(), response);
        }
    };

    public void sendMessage(String server, String message) {
        sip.sendMessage();
    }

    public boolean hasResponse onRequest(Object id) {
        responses.hasKey(id);
    }

    public JSONRPCResponse getResponse(Object id) {
        responses.get(id);
        responses.delete(id);
    }

}
```

**SIP (messenger itself):**

```
abstract class Sip {

    public void sendMessage(String msg) {
        // SIP magic
    }

    public abstract void onRequest(String msg);    
}
```

Is there a better way to do that? My biggest problems/code smells are:

- the blocking in Invoker
- the protocol is in Invoker, maybe I want to switch marshalling to something else
- the map as mean to get the correct response for a request
- the SIP abstract method looks strange
- No error handling
- No timeout

**Message Passing**

Is there an easy way to get rid of RPC, and implement something like RPC with just message passing? Any hints for pattern are welcome. I do not need the code itself, I am totally fine with just architecture. I tried to google for message passing implementations, and how they actually change state with it, but I did not find anything useful. How to implement timeout/ error handling?

Any good books/literature on that topic is also welcome, as I never programmed such distributed stuff.

Any other ideas on which protocol to use inside SIP to change state is welcome, too, as RPC was my initial thought, and I did not find anything other useful.

The code will not compile, I guess, it was just to visualize my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a service interface that has meaningful (for the us case) methods. Instead of using blocking calls, have the client supply a ResponseHandler that will be invoked when the operation is complete:

```
interface ResponseHandler {
   void onComplete(Response response);
   void onError(Throwable error);
}

interface SomeService {
   void set(String attribute, Object value, ResponsHandler responseHandler);
   void get(String attribute, ResponseHandler responseHandler);
}
```

The implementation of the Service interface can use any suitable protocol, but it has to correlate requests with responses in order to invoke the correct callbacks.

Comment: One of my problems was to correlate request/response messages. Is there some standard procedure/pattern or literature on that topic you might know?

Comment: It all depends on the protocol. If you use a SIP library like JAIN-SIP, I'm sure it can correlate the response to the request.